# Unable to run Python SDK file in Nao Robot

Tags: python-2.7

I have made a simple program using Python SDK in file say.py . Aldebaran Nao is connected to network at IP 169.254.150.108

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "169.254.150.108", 9559)
tts.say("Hello!")
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/TalkTest.py", line 3, in <module>

tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "169.254.150.108", 9559)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\naoqi.py", line 230, in __init__

inaoqi.proxy.__init__(self, args[0], args[1], args[2])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\inaoqi.py", line 322, in __init__

this = _inaoqi.new_proxy(*args)

RuntimeError:   ALNetwork::getModuleByName
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've got the same naoqi version on your robot and in your computer ?

The NAO version could be seen with for instance from your robot command line:

```
lsb_release -a
```

and then you need to install the right naoqi python:

pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-x.xx-your_platform